# Why doesn't "which myscript | xargs vim" work well?

Tags: bash, pipeline

Why doesn't

```
which myscript | xargs vim
```

work nicely?  My terminal (ubuntu 14.04) freezes when I exit vim.

Or, is there an a nice clean alternative?

Comment: BTW, I'd argue that this is probably a better question for [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) or [unix.se], being about interactive shell use more than scripting.

Comment: Thanks Charles, you obviously know how to answer this.  Could you break your answer down for me more?  Forgive me, I'm a physicist.

Comment: I've tried to extend my answer to go into more detail. If it needs to be extended further, could you perhaps ask some questions to point me in the right direction in terms of understanding what isn't currently covered?

Comment: Your expansion was exactly what I needed, thank you. Before your explanation, I hadn't come across the distinction of programs getting stdin from another program versus getting it from the terminal.  Given that, I think vim "$()" is a good solution.

Answer (score 4):

#### Why The Original Doesn't Work

You can't meaningfully pipe *anything* into vim, if you're going to use it as an interactive editor: A pipeline overrides stdin; an editor needs to be able to access your stdin (unless it's, say, interacting via X11 -- but that would be `gvim`).

To go into a little more detail: `foo | bar` runs both `foo` and `bar` at the same time, with the stdout of `foo` connected to the stdin of `bar`. Thus, `which myscript | xargs vim` has the shell originally starting two processes -- `which myscript` and `xargs vim` -- with the stdout of `which myscript` connected to the stdin of `xargs vim`.

However, this means that `xargs vim` is getting its input from `which`, and *not* from the terminal/console that the user was typing at. Thus, when `xargs vim` starts `vim`, the stdin which `vim` inherits isn't connected to the terminal either -- and `vim`, being an interactive editor built to get input from the user at a terminal, fails (perhaps spectacularly or entertainingly).

---

#### What To Do Instead

```
vim "$(which myscript)"
```

The `$()` syntax above is a [command substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst), which is replaced with the stdout of the command which it runs. As such, while this overrides the stdout of `which` (directed into a FIFO which the shell reads from for purposes of that substitution), it does not in any respect redirect the input and output handed to `vim`.

---

Alternately, if you *really* want to use `xargs` (note the following uses `-d`, a GNUism, to ensure that it works correctly when passed filenames with spaces -- though not filenames with newlines):

```
which myscript | xargs -d $'\n' sh -c 'exec vim "$@" <&2'
```

The above has `xargs`, instead of directly running vim, start a shell which copies stderr (file descriptor 2) to stdin (file descriptor 0, the default target of redirection with `<`), and *then* starts `vim`, so as to provide that copy of `vim` a file descriptor for stdin that's attached to your terminal -- if your stderr *isn't* open to your TTY, replace `<&2` with `</dev/tty` instead.